# Compare SQL Data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to check with a query if there are two different users in a giveaway.

How could I do this?

**Row**

```
1 - $250.00 - NY
2 - $200.00 - DC
```

I'd like to somehow be able to make the query check for every row and check if there are two different users in the table. Since there is User 1 and User 2 in this table it should then return `2` because there are two different users in the database, if there are 3 return `3` etc.

Is there any syntax I could use for this, or any idea on how this could be done?

Comment: If it is Oracle, you can simply do select count(column) from table

Comment: If you provide your schema we can give you the SQL Query to accomplish this.

Comment: Select count(userId) as cnt from giveaway where lookupColumn = 'x' and lookupColumn2 = 'y';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your table structure but use `DISTINCT` and it will return a list of unique values (one name of each).

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM users
```

If you wanted to count the number of entries then alter your statement to

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM users
```

Comment: No worries Sofi!

Answer (score 0):

Count() function provides the number of rows in a table. 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```